# Why Is There An Extra 20px On the Site?

Tags: css

There is an extra 20 or so pixels on the righthand side of a site I am developing. I've been combing over the CSS and can't seem to find out why.It's not so noticeable when looking at it on a computer unless you scroll over. It is apparent on a mobile devices. You can see a live example here http://gregtregunno.ca

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Hint: it's to do with your footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `footer{` in your css, change

```
padding:10px;
```

to

```
padding:10px 0;
```

It's the padding that's throwing it out.

Line `472` in your CSS.

Comment: Kind regards. So simple. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: Glad I could help! However, in future @Greg, please include actual code here so it's easier for people to find out what is wrong. (Or just enough relevant bits).

Comment: I usually do, I just couldn't find the problem and didn't think I should just post all my CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the width of the footer to 100% *plus* gave it padding. Either remove the padding, or add the rule `box-sizing: border-box;` to the footer rules.

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer. Appreciated